# How can I run Mac OSX graphical Emacs in daemon mode?

Tags: macos, emacs

Short form: I want to run the Mac OSX version of Emacs found on
http://emacsformacosx.com/ as a daemon, with graphical and text clients
connecting to it as-needed.

In detail, here is the workflow I want:

1. On login, run `/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs --daemon` to start emacs as a daemon.  *I already know how to do this*.
2. When running emacs from a local termnal, I want Either one of these:

   1. If I run `emacs` from a local command prompt, open a new frame with the selected file.
   2. If #1 is not possible, at least if I run `emacsclient` from the command line, open a new frame with the selected file.
3. When running emacs from a remote terminal, I would like a text-mode emacs to start, connected to the daemon process.
4. If I run `Emacs.app` re-use the emacs daemon that is running in the background instead of starting a new instance and open a new window on it.

So far, I am able to accomplish only #1 and #2.2 above, but those are the easy parts.  #3 and #4 are the things that are most needed in order to make this work.  Does anyone know how to accomplish these things?

Comment: For others who find this question: you can also usr `M-x server-start` to put an emacs started *without* `--daemon` into server mode. Good questions, BTW.

Comment: ... or put `(server-start)` in your .emacs so that it starts when you launch emacsa

Comment: Can someone explain how to do # 1? Would you just make it a login item?

Comment: @Charlie Flowers http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsAsDaemon#toc5

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1. *You've got this handled*
2. Yes, you'll want to use emacsclient. To get a new frame, add the -c option. I have an alias to make it quicker and to tell emacsclient not to wait for emacs server to return:

   ```
   alias em='emacsclient -n'
   ```
3. `emacsclient -nw`
4. I'm not sure about this. I start Emacs once and always load new files either within emacs or using my `em` alias.

**Update:**

Check out [this tip](http://bc.tech.coop/blog/070225.html) documenting how to use [Platypus](http://www.sveinbjorn.org/platypus) to create an app wrapper around emacsclient. You could then use *"Open With..."* to launch using your new app wrapper.

Comment: Yeah, that's the real trick, isn't it?  Because what I want is for all of the OS open calls to use the running emacs, whether I'm operating within a terminal or a GUI context.  I'll keep looking.

Comment: Found a ref to Platypus and updated my answer.

Comment: Is this solved?  How did you get Emacs.app to connect to the daemon?

Comment: I also want to know the answer to question 4 :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, here is an pretty comprehensive explain about how to do this nicely. I tried several methods to get it working nicely, but no better than what they described here.

https://gist.github.com/304964

Cheers!

Comment: The link is dead

Answer (score 1):

For 4. put this in your .emacs:

```
(setq ns-pop-up-frames nil)
```

The solution of creating a Mac .app (with Platypus) does not work because Mac won't open the same application twice.

Comment: If you use the "open -n" you can open a new instance of an application even if it's already running. Try this in the terminal: open -n -a Emacs.app somefile.txt

Comment: Yeah, but it opens a new window, which I don't want

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding what you want, but if you don't want it to create a new window but use an existing one, skip the '-n'.

Comment: Yes, I don't want to create a new window. `open -a Emacs.app` is certainly what I do, but to be opened in the same instance/daemon background of an existing emacs, I need to write `(setq ns-pop-up-frames nil)` in my `.emacs` as I wrote in my answer. Otherwise it creates a new window anyway, with or without `-n`.