# How to launch GNU emacs for OSX as emacs client?

Tags: macos, emacs, gui

I've my emacs running as server in the background, I want to launch GNU emacs MacOSX as emacsclient so that all the frames could share the same buffer whether it is in the terminal or in the GUI window.

Is any way to do that?

Comment: Do the answers to [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/50095/how-can-i-run-mac-osx-graphical-emacs-in-daemon-mode) help?

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry, if I do not understand you right.

You can run `emacs --daemon` to start console daemon and `emacsclient file.c` to edit it via this daemon.

You can run `(start-server)` in gui instance of emacs, and you will connect to it via `emacsclient file.c`. How configure editor in MacOS, I do not know.