# OS X Mountain Lion, emacsclient -c Can't Create Frame on Window System X

Tags: emacs, osx-mountain-lion, emacsclient

**EDIT:** *I have accepted the answer below because it answers my question but I wasn't aware that if one uses the x11 emacs, it is butt ugly and so I have resorted to just putting `start-server` in my init file and that way every time I start emacs.app (by clicking on it) I can then use the terminal to open more emacsclients both using -c and -t. The only drawback here is that the main emacs window has to remain open but that's the closest thing I have found to what I was actually looking for. I'd still appreciate it if someone could correct me on my approach.*

I apologize in advance if this question has already been asked and answered but I have been looking for a solution to this since this morning on both StackExchange and Google.

First off, I am a noob at both Emacs and scripting.

Alright, I have the latest Emacs.app installed from http://emacsformacosx.com and I used MacPorts to install the latest build for Emacs that runs in the Terminal. Both of these run fine but my problem is that whenever I run `emacs --daemon` from Terminal, and then try to do `emacsclient -c`, it throws the following error:

```
Waiting for Emacs...
*ERROR*: Don't know how to create a frame on window system x
```

Could someone please help me understand what's going on and how I can use both `emacsclient -c` and `emacsclient -t` without a problem?

PS: I have read [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/50095/how-can-i-run-mac-osx-graphical-emacs-in-daemon-mode) but it hasn't helped since the `-c` option spits out the error that I described above and `emacsclient` won't open if I don't give it an argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Emacs that you're running from the terminal as `emacs --daemon` isn't compiled with X Windows support.  That's what the error message means, Emacs does not know how to create an X-based frame because the code is not compiled in.  Install an Emacs with X support compiled in, run it with `--daemon`, and then you'll be able to run `emacsclient` under X or in a Terminal window.

Comment: thanks for the answer. How do I do that? MacPorts? Do I need to delete Emacs.app or is this going to be something completely different?

Comment: Nvm, I installed emacs with x11 using MacPorts. And it does the job. Do you know how I could instead use the Emacs.app to start with emacsclient -c or is that not possible?